# Magento 1.4.2 migrate customer data to new website

Tags: migration, magento-1.4

We would like to migrate our customer accounts from one website to another (new domain and company). edit: It isn't a new domain/company, but a different domain/company name.

We basically would like to migrate all the customer accounts and orders/invoices from the first website to the second.

Both websites run on 1.4.2.

What's the easiest way of getting this done without creating any duplicate entries?

Would it be easiest via phpMyAdmin/editing the SQL file directly, or is there an easier process via the backend?

Comment: Your new site, does it, or could it have no customers, no orders, no invoices, no credit memos?

Comment: Both sites are fully operational already (including customers, orders, invoices, etc). We want to delete one of the websites, but save the data and move it onto the other website.

Comment: @Theodores any further thoughts on this?

Comment: Sadly there is no simple solution to this. However you can move the customers across quite easily by exporting from one and importing into the other with the dataflow and more modern import/export tools provided.

Comment: For the orders you could put them in a fresh table and have the email address as the key. In the customer area you would need a new link - 'legacy orders' - so customers could find them. But they would not be accessible in the normal admin orders or in the reports. This is still a lot of work but there would be no unintended consequences, e.g. duplicate order ids.

Answer (score 1):

Id suggest:

1. Backup your current production site
2. Create an archives of your web root
3. Create a database dump
4. Install magento on the new server
5. After the successful installation (having tested to see that the website works) unzip the archive created in 2 overwriting the files on the new server.
6. Import the database created in 3
7. Make sure your db settings match in `app/etc/config.xml`
8. Run a full cache refresh on the site followed by a reindex

Voila, you should be all set and good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no good way to merge two installations. You can easily copy users and products as there's import-export functionality for that, but you can't transfer transactional data this way.

Things to consider:

Invoice numbers must remain unique for bookkeeping reasons and THAT can't be fixed with code, at least not easily. Since by default Magento uses automatically generated invoice numbers, it's almost 100% certain that there are going to be overlaps.

Transaction documents are related to products, payment methods, delivery methods, users and who knows what else, cross referenced by ID-s that already exist on other system. I guess there MIGHT be a way (there always is) to merge two installations (writing customer conversion tool, implementing a feature to allow non-unique Invoice numbers and so on), but it means that you must be VERY patient and have VERY deep pockets. It's easier just to transfer products and customer and deal with it as a PR issue.

Answer (score 0):

**login admin then 

go to system ->import/export ->export 

select entity type as "customers"  

click on continue button and save csv file on local pc 

now you can use this csv to import customers on other website**

*screenshot guide*
[image]